The space of solutions for an ODE on an interval containing a regular singular point
Consider the differential operator $L(y)=x^ny^{(n)}+a_1(x)x^{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+\cdots+a_n(x)x^0y^{(0)}$, where each of $a_i(x)$ has a power series expansion at $x=0$ converging for all $|x|<r_0$ for some $r_0>0$.
Then the ODE $L(y)=0$ has a regular singular point at $x=0$. It is possible to use the Frobenius method to find a basis for the space of solutions in terms of power series at $x=0$, logarithms, and $x^r$ for $r\in\mathbb{C}$. More precisely, we find a basis for the space of solutions on $(0,r_0)$ and a basis for the space of solution on $(-r_0,0)$.
Sometimes, we can glue solutions on $(-r_0,0)$ and on $(0,r_0)$ to form a solution on $(-r_0,r_0)$. For example, if $x^r$ is a solution on $(0,r_0)$ where $r$ is real and non-negative, then $x^r$ is in fact a solution on $(-r_0,r_0)$. However, if $x^{-1}$ is a solution on $(0,r_0)$, then it cannot be extended to a solution on $(-r_0,r_0)$.

My general question is whether there's a theory for solutions on intervals $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ that contain $0$ (I'm fine with taking $\varepsilon>0$ smaller than $r_0$ if necessary).

I'll try to be more specific to make this easier to answer: Write $V_{a,b}$ for the space of solutions on the interval $(a,b)$. Then we have a injective linear map $V_{-\varepsilon,\varepsilon}\to V_{-\varepsilon,0}\oplus V_{0,\varepsilon}$ given by restrictions. This shows that $\dim V_{-\varepsilon,\varepsilon}\leq 2n$ by the theory of linear ODEs without singularities.

What are the possible dimensions of $V_{-\varepsilon,\varepsilon}$ in terms of $n$?

Also:

Is it possible for a solution on $(-\varepsilon,0)$ to be extended to a solution on $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ in more than one way?


What precisely do you mean by "extend"? Can $x^2$ for $x > 0$ extend to $-x^2$ for $x < 0$?

@RobertIsrael: By extending a solution $f$ on $(-\varepsilon,0)$ I mean finding a solution $g$ on $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ such that the restriction of $g$ to $(-\varepsilon,0)$  is equal to $f$.

@RobertIsrael: So, regarding extending $x^2$ with $-x^2$, I think that the resulting function is not twice differentiable, so if $n\geq 2$ this cannot be a solution. I hope I'm not confusing things.

Well, that's not completely obvious because the $n$'th derivative has coefficient $0$ at $x=0$ in the differential equation, and others might as well.

The term $x^r$ does not have an automatic meaning for $x<0$ if $r$ is not integer. Being positive real is not sufficient. What is $(-1)^{\sqrt2}$?

Try $x^2 y''(x) - 6 x y'(x) + 12 y(x) = 0$.  $y(x) = a x^3 + b x^4$ are solutions, and since all of these have $y''(0) = 0$ you can have a solution with different $a$'s and $b$'s on $(0,+\infty)$ and on $(-\infty, 0)$.

Thank you. That's great. So, this is also a case where the dimension of the space of solutions is $2n=4$, right? Because we can choose one of $x^3,x^4$ on the left interval, and one of $x^3,x^4$ on the right interval, and the set of four possibilities is linearly independent (while by my argument in the question, the dimension cannot be larger than $2n$).
